# Erase a single pixel in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I am trying to illustrate in GIMP 2.8 with pixel-perfect precision. The pencil tool allows me to fill in a single pixel without any fuzzy edges or anti-aliasing. However, the eraser tool operates more like a brush. I want to erase a single pixel (setting it back to transparent) without disrupting any neighboring pixels. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the *tool options* for the *eraser:*

- Select the first brush (pixel).
- Select a size of 1.
- Select *hard edge.*
- Set Dynamics to *Dynamics off*

Then the eraser should do what you want.

(Also, do not forget that you need an alpha channel on the respective layer.)